# Initializing a nested structure throws error in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I am learning structures in C++. Got the following error while executing the code:

Error: Too many initializer for CompData.

It would be great if someone could point out the mistake.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct EmpData
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double salary;
};

struct DepartmentData
{
    std::string departmentName;
    struct EmpData;
};

struct CompData
{
    std::string compName;
    struct DepartmentData;
};

int main()
{
    CompData DeltaF 
    {
        "DeltaF",
        {
            "Product Development",
            {
                "Steve", 35, 1223
            }
        }
    };
    
}
```

Comment: `struct EmpData;` doesn't do what you think it does. You need something like `EmpData data;`

Comment: In C++ you don't need to prepend `struct` keyword to declare a variable with a structure type, like you need with C. What you are actually doing in your `DepartmentData` type is [declaring a nested type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types).

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
struct DepartmentData
{
    std::string departmentName;
    struct EmpData;
};
```

You declare a structure `EmpData`, full name is `DepartmentData::EmpData`. It is a different type than `EmpData` you declared and defined above. If you want `DepartmentData` to have a member of type `EmpData` you can remove `struct` and need to give it a name:

```
struct DepartmentData
{
    std::string departmentName;
    EmpData empData;             // member of type EmpData called empData
};
```

Same for the `DepartmentData` member of `CompData`. If you fix those, your code compiles without errors.